# Calendar Draggable events always return allDay:true

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have problem with Calendar external events:
I just use this Draggable code

```
new Draggable('#event-container', {
      itemSelector: '.external-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
           return {
          title: 'event-title',
          allDay:false,
          start: '12:30:00',
          duration: '2:00:00',
        };
      }
});
```

In this case , i can drop **only** on Day view, but **not** on Month view.

If i **remove** the `duration` parameter, then i can drop the event on Month view.

In **both cases**, the `"eventReceive"` function always returns an event with `allDay:true` ... instead of range event.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Added snippet.
We have many errors in console that i don't see on my private server

```js
        var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
        var Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;

        var containerEl = document.getElementById('operatori_list');
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      
        var cal = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            locale: 'it',
            eventDisplay:'block',
            headerToolbar: {
            left  : 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },

            events: [], 

            editable  : true,
            droppable : true, 


            drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
                console.log('drop', this);
                console.log('drop', arguments);
            },


            eventReceive: function(info) { 
                console.log('eventReceive', info);
            },
     

        });

        cal.render();
        
        
        
        
      new Draggable(containerEl, {
          itemSelector: '.fc-event',
          eventData: function(eventEl) {

          return {
            allDay:false, 
            title: eventEl.innerText,
             start: $(eventEl).attr("data-starttime"),
             duration: $(eventEl).attr("data-timeduration"),
          };

          }
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.js"></script>

    <div id="operatori_list" class="dragWrapper">
      <div class="fc-event external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" title="Event 1" data-starttime="08:00:00" data-endtime="18:00:00" data-timeduration="10:00:00">Event 1 </div>
      <div class="fc-event external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" title="Event 2" data-starttime="08:00:00" data-endtime="18:00:00" data-timeduration="10:00:00">Event 2 </div>
      <div class="fc-event external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" title="Event 3" data-starttime="08:00:00" data-endtime="18:00:00" data-timeduration="10:00:00">Event 3 </div>
    </div>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: What version of fullCalendar are you using? What exact code are you using in eventReceive? I'm happy to help but you need to [edit] the question with a [mre] of the issue so that we have enough information to understand everything, then it will be much easier to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Edited with additional data. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). For your question to be on-topic on Stackoverflow you need to post a [mre] of the problem **here** in your question so it will stay the same even after you fix your website, so that the question makes sense and is still useful for other readers coming with similar issues in future. You can use the Code Snippet feature to make a runnable demo right here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The snippet error is probably because you forgot `<div id="calendar"></div>` in the HTML!

Comment: Thanks for updating again. Just so you know I don't have time to go into it in detail right now, but I will try and get to it in a few days

Comment: @ADyson thanks in advance ;)

Comment: UP for this subject..